# How to combine two differently typed sequences into tuples in f#?

Tags: f#

I'm a bit new to F#, I have mostly c# background.
I'm working with two lists/sequences that represent the same thing, but from different datasources (one is  a local file, the other is a group of items in an online system.

I need to report the mismatches between the two datasets.

So far I have filtered down the two lists to contain only items that aren't have mismatches in the other dataset.

Now I want to pair them up into tuples (or anything else really) based on one of the properties so I can log the differences.

So far what I've tried is this:

```
 let printDiff (offlinePackages: oP seq) (onLinePackages: onP seq) =
                                                                    Seq.map2(fun x y -> (x, y)) offlinePackages onLinePackages
```

This does pair up my data, however I'd still need some logic to do the pairup based on their matching property value.
I'm looking for something like:

```
if offLinePackage.Label = OnlinePackage.Label then /do the matchup/
else /don't do anything/
```

I know I'm still stuck in my object oriented thinking, that's also why I'm asking.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching sequence elements based on some equivalency function - that's called "join".

The most "straightforward" way to do a join is to get a Cartesian product and filter it down, like this:

```
let matchup seq1 seq2 = 
    Seq.allPairs seq1 seq2
    |> Seq.filter (fun (x, y) -> x.someProp = y.someProp)
```

Or in a computation expression form:

```
let matchup seq1 seq2
    seq {
      for x in seq1 do
      for y in seq2 do
      if x.someProp = y.someProp then yield (x,y)
    }
```

But this is a bit inefficient. The complexity would be O(n*m), because it iterates over all possible pairs. Fine if the lists are short, but will bite you the more you scale.

To do this more efficiently, you can use the `query` computation builder and its operation `join`, which does a hash-join (i.e. it builds a hashtable first and then matches the elements based on that):

```
let matchup seq1 seq2 =
  query {
    for x in seq1 do
    join y in seq2 on (x.someProp = y.someProp)
    select (x,y)
  }
```